# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError with webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) in selenium python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have an error with webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) I don't understand, it used to work but it doesn't anymore, could you please help me ? :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Autobet\test\test_oddsportal.py", line 32, in <module>
    data = test_oddsportal()
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Autobet\test\test_oddsportal.py", line 27, in test_oddsportal
    df = OddsPortal.get_data(a)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Autobet\scraping\oddsportal.py", line 891, in get_data
    driver = OddsPortal.login('ParionsPro', 'fb00296b')
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Autobet\scraping\oddsportal.py", line 97, in login
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 39, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 26, in _get_driver_path
    binary_path = self.driver_cache.find_driver(driver)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 101, in find_driver
    metadata = self.get_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 135, in get_metadata
    return json.load(outfile)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\autobet\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 14 column 46 (char 638)
```

Apparently it doesn't find what it's looking for in find_driver. I tried to uninstall and install back webdriver-manager but it's not working

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on without more information. Could you perhaps post the code that is causing this error?

Comment: Are you getting error on this `webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` line ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by writing the path !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).